# How to get values that are in every unique adjacent value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get all of the oid values that are in a row with every vid value in a given table. An example of such a table, call it Temp1, is seen here:

```
oid vid
-------
 1   6
 1   6
 5   6
 5   6
 5   6
 8   6
 8   7
 4   8
 5   8
 8   8
 4   9
 6   9
 5   9
 6   9
 8   9
```

As you can see in this table, only the oid value of 8 is in a row with every vid value. There can be repeated rows, and the oid and vid values could be any integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select t.oid
from Temp1 t
group by t.oid
having count(distinct vid) = (select count(distinct t2.vid) from Temp1 t2);
```